# Memory limit error using ffmpeg on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, memory, ffmpeg

I have a Flask app running on Heroku and what I am trying to do is use FFmpeg to re-encode a video to x265. For that, I have the following route

```
@app.route('/x265', methods=['POST'])
def rotax265():
    up_file = request.files['file'].stream

    in_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    in_file.write(up_file.read())
    in_file.seek(0)
    out_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()

    conv = VideoConverter(in_file, out_file)

    conv.x265()
    out_file.seek(0)
    
    return out_file.read()
```

It uses a `VideoConverter` class that I created:

```
class VideoConverter(object):
    def __init__(self, in_file, out_file):
        self.input = in_file
        self.output = out_file

    def x265(self, read_chunk_size=-1):
        args = (
            ffmpeg
            .input('pipe:', format='matroska')
            .output('pipe:', vcodec='libx265', format='matroska')
            .get_args()
        )

        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ['ffmpeg'] + args, stdin=self.input, stdout=self.output)
        p.wait()
```

This class is using [`ffmpeg-python`](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) and `subprocess` modules.

I am using pipe both in input and output so that I don't use storage space and avoid receiving R-14 errors (memory quota exceeded).

This works as expected when running locally, but when I try to run the script on the Heroku server, it still returns R-14 errors.

Is there any way I can avoid getting those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using pipe both in input and output so that I don't use storage space and avoid receiving R-14 errors (memory quota exceeded).

Storage (disk) and memory (RAM) are different things. This error is about *memory*.

Your pipes may prevent you from writing to disk, but they don't do anything to reduce memory usage. In fact, they may *increase* memory usage—the data must exist *somewhere*, and if it can't be written to disk it needs to stay in memory.

If you're getting memory issues on Heroku you only have two options:

- Use less memory
- Upgrade your dyno to ones with more memory

Video conversion generally takes a lot of memory, and I'm not aware of any good ways of reducing that aside from working with very short video clips. This leaves you with one real option: invest in bigger dynos.